# Update text at certain slider values

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code so far.

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length);
var currentText = random;
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = texts[random];
```

So, every time the HTML page is updated, a random text from an array is selected. I also have a slider in the code.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.001" value="0" class="slider" id="wordSlider">
```

Finally, I have another array of texts, with each text being a continuation of the previous array's texts at the respective index. What I want to do is update the text from the initial array to a new array at a specific range value, for example, 0.5. How can I do this? I tried using conditionals, but it seems that the code only checks for the variable value once at runtime.

EDIT:
An example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
<script>
    (function getText() {
        var texts = ["Text 1 Part 1", "Text 2 Part 1", "Text 3 Part 1"];
                        
        var texts2 = ["Text 1 Part 2", "Text 2 Part 2", "Text 3 Part 2"];
                    
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length);
        var currentText = random;
                        
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = texts[currentText];                                                                         
    })();           
</script>
```

The page might randomly select the first text in the *texts* array. Once the slider reaches 0.5, the text will change to "story 1 part 2", the text in the second array with the same index.

EDIT 2:
In case anyone is wondering, this was my final solution (credit to @SomoKRoceS)

Script tag:

```
<script>
    const texts = [
            ["Text 1 Part 1", "Text 1 Part 2", "Text 1 Part 3"],
            ["Text 2 Part 1", "Text 2 Part 2", "Text 2 Part 3"],
            ["Text 3 Part 1", "Text 3 Part 2", "Text 3 Part 3"]
    ];

    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length);
    const currentText = random;
                    
    <!-- The text currently displayed -->
    var displayed = document.getElementById("text"); 

    function getText(part) {
            displayed.innerHTML = texts[currentText][part];
    }

    <!-- Get the first (index 0) of a random set of texts -->
    getText(0);
                        
    </script>
```

In my div where the slider is located, I added:

```
<script>
    slider.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        if(e.target.value > 0.25 && e.target.value < 0.5) {
            getText(1);
        } else if (e.target.value >= 0.5) {
            getText(2);
        } else {
            getText(0);
        }                   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use the `onchange` event, get the value of the slider, then check if that value is the one you're looking for.

Comment: You should make [mre] with sample data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen to the change event of the slider, like this:

```
var slideElem = document.getElementById("wordSlider");

slideElem.addEventListener("change", event => {
  if (slideElem.value < 0.5) {
    getText(0);
  } else {
    getText(1);
  }
});
```

When `getText` is the function:

```
function getText(part) {
  var texts = [
    ["Text 1 Part 1", "Text 2 Part 1", "Text 3 Part 1"],
    ["Text 1 Part 2", "Text 2 Part 2", "Text 3 Part 2"],
    ["Text 1 Part 3", "Text 2 Part 3", "Text 3 Part 3"]
  ];

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length);
  var currentText = random;

  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = texts[part][currentText];
}
```

(I also turned the `texts` into a list of lists for generalization).

Full Snippet:

```js
function getText(part) {
  var texts = [
    ["Text 1 Part 1", "Text 2 Part 1", "Text 3 Part 1"],
    ["Text 1 Part 2", "Text 2 Part 2", "Text 3 Part 2"],
    ["Text 1 Part 3", "Text 2 Part 3", "Text 3 Part 3"]
  ];

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length);
  var currentText = random;

  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = texts[part][currentText];
}

getText(0);

var slideElem = document.getElementById("wordSlider");

slideElem.addEventListener("change", event => {
  if (slideElem.value < 0.5) {
    getText(0);
  } else {
    getText(1);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <span id="text"></span>
    <br />
    <input
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="1"
      step="0.001"
      value="0"
      class="slider"
      id="wordSlider"
    />
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please notice that every part change the random will be applied, if you want to stick with the same text (so teh random will be executed only once, you should use it as a const when the scrip loads. Like this:

Full Snippet:

```js
const texts = [
  ["Text 1 Part 1", "Text 2 Part 1", "Text 3 Part 1"],
  ["Text 1 Part 2", "Text 2 Part 2", "Text 3 Part 2"],
  ["Text 1 Part 3", "Text 2 Part 3", "Text 3 Part 3"]
];

const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length);
const currentText = random;

function getText(part) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = texts[part][currentText];
}

getText(0);

var slideElem = document.getElementById("wordSlider");

slideElem.addEventListener("change", event => {
  if (slideElem.value < 0.5) {
    getText(0);
  } else {
    getText(1);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <span id="text"></span>
    <br />
    <input
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="1"
      step="0.001"
      value="0"
      class="slider"
      id="wordSlider"
    />
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Right now the slider has two parts.. If you want to generalize it depends on the size of the Parts, you should get the length of `texts` and split the threshold of the slider into `texts.length` parts. Like this:

```
    slideElem.addEventListener("change", event => {
      let splitThreshold = 1/texts.length;
      let wantedPart = Math.floor(slideElem.value/splitThreshold);
      if(wantedPart>=texts.length)
        wantedPart=texts.length-1;
      getText(wantedPart);
    });
```

Full snippet:

```js
const texts = [
  ["Text 1 Part 1", "Text 2 Part 1", "Text 3 Part 1"],
  ["Text 1 Part 2", "Text 2 Part 2", "Text 3 Part 2"],
  ["Text 1 Part 3", "Text 2 Part 3", "Text 3 Part 3"]
];

const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length);
const currentText = random;

function getText(part) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = texts[part][currentText];
}

getText(0);

var slideElem = document.getElementById("wordSlider");

    slideElem.addEventListener("change", event => {
      let splitThreshold = 1/texts.length;
      let wantedPart = Math.floor(slideElem.value/splitThreshold);
      if(wantedPart>=texts.length)
        wantedPart=texts.length-1;
      getText(wantedPart);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <span id="text"></span>
    <br />
    <input
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="1"
      step="0.001"
      value="0"
      class="slider"
      id="wordSlider"
    />
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom events to achieve this.

1. Dynamically render the text you want to change, and listen for the custom event.
2. Add an event listener to the slider as well.
3. When the slider gets a value at which you need the text to change, trigger the custom event you created.
4. In the listener on the display text, update it to "story 1 part 2" or whatever.

```
const d = document;

let event = new Event('trigger');

let text = d.getElementById('#id-of-text-field');
let slider = d.querySelector('.slider'); // use ID if possible

text.innerText = 'story 1 part 1';

text.addEventListener('trigger', function () {
  text.innerText = 'story 1 part 2';
});

slider.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
  if (event.target.value == 0.5) {
    text.dispatchEvent('trigger');
  }
})
```